# Can't execute bash command for path in environment variable that contains spaces

Tags: bash

I want to count the lines of a file in a folder with a space in its name. I unfortunately cannot change the folder name, it will always have a space in it.

```
$ export MYPATH=a\ folder/trigrams.txt
$ wc -l $MYPATH
wc: a: open: No such file or directory
wc: folder/trigrams.txt: open: No such file or directory
       0 total

$ export MYPATH="a\ folder/trigrams.txt"
$ wc -l $MYPATH
wc: a\: open: No such file or directory
wc: folder/trigrams.txt: open: No such file or directory
   0 total

$ wc -l "$MYPATH"
wc: a\ folder/trigrams.txt: open: No such file or directory

$ wc -l a\ folder/trigrams.txt 
70803 a folder/trigrams.txt
```

Comment: `wc -l "$MYPATH"`

Comment: You have to assign like `MYPATH='a folder/trigrams.txt'` and then use `wc -l "$MYPATH"`; you added a literal backslash in your latest edit.